# Relative hyperlinking failing

Tags: php, html, css

I am using relative hyperlinking for a website i am building. The code structure looks like:

```
/root/website1/
```

all my code is under website1 folder.

website 1 looks like:

```
/css
   style.css
/static
   header.php
   footer.php
   page1.php
page3.php
page4.php
```

Now, i am using `style.css` inside `header.php` and including `header.php` in `page1.php` and `page3.php`.

`style.css` 's path fails for either of the two page if i use it like:

```
css/style.css
```

or

```
../css/style.css
```

since, the browser finds the css relative to the path of page it is included in. Is there a way i can include `header.php` and get the css working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, and because `page1.php` and `page3.php` aren't located on the same dir, you'll need to provide the `absolute url` to `style.css` inside `header.php`, ex: `http://site.tld/css/style.css`.

Comment: that is one option i had in mind but i would be moving to a different server in next few days...so was thinking of alternatives

Comment: @CodeMonkey consider it, otherwise will need to write more code and it's a waste of time for such a simple solution. ;)